# Having issues with referenced libraries in Eclipse (cross platform compatibility)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I'm working on a side project at work creating a GUI in Eclipse (using Windowbuilder). Anyways, when I create a new Java/SWT project, it automatically adds the referenced libraries into the project (located in the plugins folder).

My issue is that I'm using git so I can work on my Macbook at home and my Windows computer at work, and that when I pulled the files to my Mac the libraries were pointing to the absolute path on my PC.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this in eclipse, you can right click on the "Referenced Libraries" folder -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path. In the opened Properties setting box, you can fix the build path to point to correct location of libraries on your Macbook.

Comment: Do I have to redo each one individually? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: you can specify the path and then copy the required libraries to that path.